# get 3d model from server and display in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A model is stored in 000webhost server. I want to get it in unity using script. I am new in unity an I can,t understand it. If someone helpls me I will be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to make AssetBundle from you model.

create this script in your project:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
public class AssetbundleCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
[MenuItem("Assets/Build Assetbundle")]
 static void Create()
 {
    BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/", // path where your assetbundle will be saved
                                    BuildAssetBundleOptions.None,
                                    BuildTarget.Android); // or any platform you want.
 }
}
#endif
```

After you save this code, 'Build Assetbundle' will be appeared in Assets.

You have to enter name for your assetbundle, select the prefab you want to make assetbundle with, In the inspector tab, on the bottom add name

[image]

Then press Build AssetBundle which i mentioned earlier.

After you upload Assetbundle on your server, you can download and instantiate it in your scene easily using:

```
void Start()
{
    string url = "your url here";

    StartCoroutine(DownloadModel(url));
}

IEnumerator DownloadModel(string url)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null)
    {
        AssetBundle assetBundle = www.assetBundle;
        GameObject gameObject = Instantiate(assetBundle.LoadAsset("model name")) as GameObject;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: After you save this code, 'Build Assetbundle' will be appeared in Assets.But in my case BuildAssetbundle is not appearing. i u can help please

Comment: it wont be in folder "asets", but in top bar (where file,edit,assets,gameboject... are)

Comment: Thankyou very much